# Get Object by name method not working

Tags: java, android, string, list, object

I have an "Item" object that is defined as follows:

```
Item odysseusBow = new Item(getString(R.string.odysseus_bow_name), R.drawable.odysseus_bow, 2100, 'P', 'I',
                0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0.4, 0,
                0, 0, 0,  
                getString(R.string.odysseus_bow_passive));
```

Where "R.string.odysseus_bow_name" = "Odysseus\' Bow". The first parameter is the item name, which can be returned using .getName( ).

This Item is added to a static list of items called "items".

I then use a method to get the Item by name:

```
public Item getItemByName(String name) {
        Item x = new Item();
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).getName().equals(name))
                x = items.get(i);
        }
        return x;
    }
```

This method has worked for every Item in the list except for this particular one; the item is always null.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

EDIT: More relevant code:

```
final Item item = getItemByName(holder.item1Name.getText().toString());
TextView itemName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_header_name);
```

The text of "itemName" is "Odysseus' Bow". Also, the formatting of the apostrophe is not the issue since I have other items with apostrophes within their names that function as expected.

Comment: Can you share all the relevant code? Like how you are calling it, etc. Also, did you try debugging?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my question now

Comment: Would definitely recommend debugging as likely seems a typo (since we're dealing with strings). Otherwise, write an equality check loop comparing each char to see if that brings any insight.

Comment: I'll try the char equality method, but debugging hasn't helped me. Thanks for the advice